# LESS syntax highlighting and intellisense stopped working in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, less, syntax-highlighting, intellisense, web-essentials

I'm running Visual Studio 2012.3 update.

Today when I started IDE and opened a LESS file, syntax highlighting didn't work. Nor did intellisense while editing it.

It seems that Web Essentials is working as CSS preview pane is displayed and code in it is syntax highlighted. And I can also set Web Essentials' properties in Options and they do apply.

**What's wrong?** Anybody experiencing the same issue?

Comment: I don't know how your system is set up, but LESS just pushed out version 1.4.1 (right on the heels of 1.4.0), so if your automatically capturing the latest LESS updates, maybe the update is messing with your Web Essentials interface (just a thought to look into, not really an answer).

Comment: @ScottS: What does that have to do with Visual Studio LESS plugin? Nothing really. I'm not sure which LESS version VS supports, but it doesn't really matter. It used to highlight my LESS code, and after 2012.3 it stopped doing that.

Comment: I'm not sure if it has anything to do with it or not (which is why I put it as a comment). I don't use VS (so I'm not talking from experience), but I did know that LESS had an update, so I was offering that as a possible area to look into in that _perhaps_ the LESS code being produced by the LESS update messed up the VS interface for highlighting. I offered that purely as a source of finding cause. It may have nothing to do with it, and in fact be purely an issue due to the VS 2012.3 (even with earlier LESS versions).

Comment: @ScottS: I expect Visual Studio LESS plugin to incorporate a parser to make highlighting and intellisense work. Whether that particular parser is up to date with latest LESS version (which I seriously doubt) is a different question. But I'm more than sure that an update of LESS *standard* doesn't interfere with Visual Studio. Until they update the plugin that is of course. But thanks for your alternative idea...

Comment: I have this exact issue with v3 of Web Essentials. The Web Tools 2012.2 doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @cirrus: I installed Windows 8.1 Preview and due to its installation nature I had to reinstall all my software. When installing VS I then went straight to Update 3 and installed WebEssentials and everything seems to work fine now. It must be something wring with installation of these parts. I suspect. Try reinstalling VS and addons and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

LESS was moved into the ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2 which you can read about and download here: http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/aspnet-45/aspnet-and-web-tools-20122-release-notes

It is unclear why Web Essentials continues to say it features LESS. The changelog states that the LESS editor was dropped in 2.5. This is the only place that I could find that mentions the move: http://madskristensen.net/post/Web-Tools-20122-and-Web-Essentials.aspx